# Error al cambiar permisos - Tinymce: Responsive FileManager

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

Al parecer, tengo bien integrado *ResponsiveFilemanager* con *TinyMCE*, pero al cambiar los permisos de archivos y directorios, se genera un error, y no muestra el mensaje que le corresponde que sería algo como: No tiene permisos.

Específicamente solo he dejado que el usuario cargue archivos y cree directorios, pero nada de mover, copiar, pegar, cortar, editar, eliminar.

Entonces, por ejemplo, cuando intento mover un archivo, se generaron errores con el archivo **execute.php**, **ajax_calls.php**, y siempre anda con una variable `$_POST[ 'path' ]`, como `undefined index`.

Algo curioso que descubrí fue que al dejar el privilegio de `rename_files` en `true`, todo funcionaba normalmente. Pareciera que hubiera un conflicto con ese parámetro de configuración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
case 'copy_cut':
    if($_POST[sub] != 'copy' && $_POST['sub_action'] != 'cut')
    {
        response(trans('wrong sub-action').AddErrorLocation())->send();
        exit;
    }
    if (strpos($_POST['path'],'../') !==FALSE
        || strpos($_POST['path'],'./') !==FALSE
        || strpos($_POST['path'],'..\\') !==FALSE
        || strpos($_POST['path'],'.\\') !==FALSE
    {
        response(trans('wrong path'.AddErrorLocation()))->send();
        exit;
    }
    if(trim($_POST['path']) == '')
    {
        response(trans('no path').AddErrorLocation())->send();
    }
    $msg_sub_action = ($_POST['sub_action'] == 'copy' ? trans('Copy') : trans('Cut') );
    $path = $current_path . $_POST['path'];

    if (is_dir($path))
    {
        // can't copy/cut dirs
        if($copy_cut_dirs === false)
        {
            response(sprintf(trans('Copy_Cut_Not_Allowed'), $msg_sub_action, trans('Folders')).AddErrorLocation())->send();
            //...
        }
        //...
    }
    //...
```

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que veo, en tu archivo `ajax_calls.php` envías datos al servidor. Un ejemplo de envío sería: `http://www.example.com/ajax_calls.php?id=3&path=documentos` En ese caso podrás recuperar a través de `$_POST` dos valores: `$_POST[ 'id' ]` y `$_POST[ 'path' ]` El **error** te está diciendo que **dentro de lo que envías al servidor no hay nada que se llame `path`** Nota: Cuando preguntes, se te puede ayudar más si colocas parte del código que estás usando en lugar de imágenes. Saludos.

Comment: Esos son archivos propio de Responsive - Filemanager, en dado caso lo único configurable es el archivo config.php, donde cambié privilegios a conveniencia como lo indica la documentación. Sin embargo está generando esos errores. Es posible (de hecho así es) y bien como lo indicas las variables no están siendo pasadas. Tengo la impresión que tiene que ver con el archivo Dialog.php (vista emergente con el explorador de archivos) allí puede ser donde se está haciendo el llamada a la URL sin parámetros.

Comment: le has quitado la opcion de copiar, clonar o mover el archivo y cuando lo haces te lanza el error esto es debido a que todavia tienes la clase "draggable" te recomiendo que lo quites por medio de javascript o otro medio como gustes y solucionas ese error